# Turbo frame not loading html when using src attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbo, hotwire

I am trying to load html into a turbo frame using the src attribute, but when I load the page the frame exists on I don't see a network request being issued to get the html.

This is the markup I have written on the rendered page:

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag "new_message", src: new_room_message_path(@room), target: "_top" do %>
  <div>
    placeholder
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And the matching turbo frame in the `new_room_message_path` view:

```
<h1>New Message</h1>
<%= turbo_frame_tag "new_message", target: "_top" do %>
  <%= form_with(model: [ @message.room, @message ]) do |form| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= form.text_field :content %>
      <%= form.submit "send" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

When I visit the `new_room_message_path` in the browser the route and html look good.

application.js contents:

```
// Entry point for the build script in your package.json
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "./controllers"
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap"
```

I am running this on `rails 7.0.2.3`.
I have the `gem "turbo-rails"` installed.
I see turbo being imported in the application.js `import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"`.

Any tips on config or code changes I should try or am outright missing? If there's any more context that would be helpful, im happy to update the question.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Check to make sure that you have Turbo actually loaded in the browser:  `window.Turbo`

Comment: @Jbur43 Have you sorted this out? I am having the very same issue right now 

Comment: @DanielBatalla I think my issue ended up being that I didn't specify a bundling option for javascript, I built a new app using the command `rails new pizzawhat -j esbuild --css tailwind` and it worked after that

Answer (score 2):

I had the very same problem *(with almost the same content in `applications.js` file)* when upgrading from **RoR v6.1** with `webpacker` to **RoR v7.0** with `importmap`.

When I installed `importmap-rails` gem, I didn't make a step [that is stated in the README](https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails#how-do-importmaps-work) of the gem:

```
./bin/rails importmap:install
```

This task will create all the files and folders required by `importmap` to run properly in the Rails project, including `config/impormap.rb`. In this file, I added the following content:

```
pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
```

After adding that, I restarted the server and everything worked perfectly.